# Java could not find symbol in OOP program

Tags: java, oop

I'm currently following a Java programming tutorial on FreeCodeCamp and encountered an issue while coding along. I'm using Visual Studio Code with necessary extentions or at least i hope so. The error occurs when I run the Library class, and I'm unable to resolve it.
all the files are under a folder called OOP and only these files are present with respective class files

```java
package OOP;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class User {
    public String name;
    public LocalDate birthday;
}
```

This the first file in the OOP folder

```java
package OOP;
import java.time.LocalDate;
// import java.util.*;
// import OOP.Users;

public class Library {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        User youngerUser = new User();

        youngerUser.name = "User Junior";
        youngerUser.birthday = LocalDate.parse("2007-01-31");

        System.out.printf("%s was born back in %s", youngerUser.name, youngerUser.birthday.toString());
    }
}
```

This is the second file

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Library.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
User youngerUser = new User();
^
symbol:   class User
location: class Library
Library.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
User youngerUser = new User();
                       ^
symbol:   class User
location: class Library
2 errors
```

i have tried everything but i cannot figure out how to fix it. the problem continues when i use cli for running or use code runner

Comment: If you put the files in the correct directories, and compile it the right way, your code compiles correctly.  (I tried.  It does.)

Comment: i just tried to open the OOP folder directly in vs code and removing the package OOP lines and it works just fine i don't know why but it works but i would still like to know how to fix the original problem

Comment: BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Package names shoud be lower case

Comment: You need to read about how packages work; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html

Comment: it might be entirely because of the package OOP line if i remove it the file runs fine but shows red squiggly lines on top of the code but it runs fine

Comment: share the project structure please

Comment: @AranyaDebKesh - Read the tutorial.  Just read it.  It will explain what you did wrong.

Comment: And don’t say you’ve tried everything. You haven’t. It’s just meaningless.

Comment: believe me i read it but it doesn't answer my question when i use it my program shows those errors and when i remove it the program runs fine but it shows error that expected declaration but the program still runs

Comment: the root folder is named java and inside it there is a folder called OOP and there are other files outside of OOP folder and inside OOP folder there are files User.java User.class and Library.java Library.class